# phantomJS scraping with breaks not working

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, sleep

I'm trying to scrape some URLS from a webservice, its working perfect but I need to scrape something like 10,000 pages from the same web servicve.

I do this by creating multiple phantomJS processes and they each open and evaluate a different URL (Its the same service, all I change is one parameter in the URL of the website).

Problem is I don't want to open 10,000 pages at once, since I don't want their service to crash, and I don't want my server to crash either.

I'm trying to make some logic of opening/evaluating/insertingToDB ~10 pages, and then sleeping for 1 minute or so.

Let's say this is what I have now:

```
var numOfRequests = 10,000; //Total requests
    for (var dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < numOfRequests; dataIndex++) {
         phantom.create({'port' : freeport}, function(ph) { 
           ph.createPage(function(page) {
             page.open("http://..." + data[dataIncFirstPage], function(status) {
```

I want to insert somewhere in the middle something like:

```
if(dataIndex % 10 == 0){
   sleep(60); //I can use the sleep module
}
```

Every where I try to place [sleepJS](https://www.npmjs.org/package/sleep) the program crashes/freezes/loops forever...

Any idea what I should try?

I've tried placing the above code as the first line after the for loop, but this doesn't work (maybe because of the callback functions that are waiting to fire..)
If I place it inside the `phantom.create()` callback also doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realize that NodeJS runs asynchronously and in your for-loop, each method call is being executing one after the other. That `phantom.create` call finishes near immediately, and then the next cycle of the for-loop kicks in.

To answer your question, you want the sleep command at the end of the `phantom.create` block, still in side the for-loop. Like this:

```
var numOfRequests = 10000; // Total requests
for( var dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < numOfRequests; dataIndex++ ) {
  phantom.create( { 'port' : freeport }, function( ph ) {
    // ..whatever in here
  } );
  if(dataIndex % 10 == 0){
    sleep(60); //I can use the sleep module
  }
}
```

Also, consider using a package to help with these control flow issues. Async is a good one, and [has a method, `eachLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachLimit) that will concurrently run a number of processes, up to a limit. Handy! You will need to create an input object array for each iteration you wish to run, like this:

```
var dataInputs = [ { id: 0, data: "/abc"}, { id : 1, data : "/def"} ];
function processPhantom( dataItem, callback ){
  console.log("Starting processing for " + JSON.stringify( dataItem ) );
  phantom.create( { 'port' : freeport }, function( ph ) {
    // ..whatever in here. 
    //When done, in inner-most callback, call:
    //callback(null); //let the next parallel items into the queue
    //or 
    //callback( new Error("Something went wrong") ); //break the processing
  } );
}
async.eachLimit( dataInputs, 10, processPhantom, function( err ){
  //Can check for err.
  //It is here that everything is finished.
  console.log("Finished with async.eachLimit");
});
```

Sleeping for a minute isn't a bad idea, but in groups of 10, that will take you 1000 minutes, which is over 16 hours! Would be more convenient for you to only call when there is space in your queue - and be sure to log what requests are in process, and have completed.

Comment: Thanks - What am I supposed to put in the eachLimit params? I've looked at it before but couldn't find the way to make it fit. I know that node is async and I'm aware of when and how the methods run. But would it not create a problem that my main process is going to sleep while a phantom child is done evaluating a page? and if 5 phantom processes are done evaluating, and my main is sleeping...what will this cause?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Also, it does not matter that your main process "is sleeping." NodeJS is also Event Driven, so it will happily wait for an Event to fire, and that Event can be the completion of your phantom process or another callback from a different part of the code. If 5 finish at the same time, node will handle each in a single-threaded manner (as in, one at a time).

Comment: I think I'm still having problems with the Async, how would I control when to callback the new error? if what happens should i call the callback with an error?

Comment: If you call the callback with an error, it will break the async processing. So should a minor error occur, just log it and move on. Only if you want to stop all processing should the callback be called with an error.